# Trouble beginning with RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I just finished writing a rake task for a ruby rails project that will be run locally (never online). To test it, I'm trying to use RSpec, which is what the app has been using for its unit tests so far.

I've never used RSpec before and I'm having a lot of trouble. Here's a general list of my problems:

1) The "spec_helper" file queries an online server, which I don't need and which has been giving me some connection problems

2) I can't figure out how to require the files I need to test

I patched these problems, but here is my current require list...

```
# require 'spec_helper'
require '../../../lib/release_notes/release_notes_generator'
```

Definitely not what I'm looking for.

3) I'm in the wrong working directory. Up to this point, the rake task has only been run from a specific directory, and now I can't figure out how to get RSpec to run it from a different one.

How should I fix these problems? Should I be applying RSpec to this problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/release_notes/release_notes_generator"
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this will work -- Rails.root returns nil for me